# Laravel: PHP Artisan Tinker 'SQLSTATE[23000]' error

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, command-prompt

So I am going through a series of intro videos to laravel and I am at the Database migration part and am struggling with a few things...

Here is the error...
[image]

I have a) no idea what it means or is referring to as this is my first foray into real command prompt usage and b) how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

regards.

**EDIT-1:** Here is my migration file...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCardsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('cards');
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Here is my command prompt, it is working with the answer below, but now with the original laracast tutorial.
[image]

Comment: Please add your migration_file

Comment: Something is missing in the migration file. Did you copy some source code directly? I suspect that later in the course, you'll add some logic to tie cards to users, so in another migration file, that column will be added. I think your source is beyond the step in the course that you're following.

Comment: here is my resource: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/7?autoplay=true play from 9:00

Comment: You might have some leftovers, that should definitely work. Try `php artisan migrate:refresh`, then the original command again.

Comment: your schema doesn't have user_id ?

Comment: i guess  ur **cards** schema u want insert with auth id ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have to supply a user-id as your schema dictates that a card belongs to a user. Add `['user_id'=>some user id]` to your array.

Alternatively, create a `cards` relation on your `User`-model:

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function cards()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Card::class);
   }
}
```

This way, you can create a card like so (assuming you have a user variable, fx. by calling `User::first()`, `User::find($id)` etc.):

```
$user->cards()->create([...])
```

Comment: trying that now, what gets me is that I followed the instructor to the letter (in their 2016 up-to-date course) and get this error.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that they use `DateTime` as well; normally, you'd use the extended `Carbon` package. That's what Eloquent casts its own date fields to. Which course are you following? I guess I'm questioning the quality a bit.

Comment: This is coming straight from laracasts 101 laravel course and I am just following along... here is my command... DB::table('cards')->insert(['user_id'=> 1, 'title' => 'My new Card', 'created_at' => new DateTime, 'updated_at' => new DateTime]);

Comment: It seems to have worked, just testing a little further

Comment: If it's Laracasts, it's definitely good quality. That code you posted should work.

Comment: So strange, the migration file you showed us has no user_id field... Looks like a DB purge and migrating again should work out for you

Comment: Okay so the command definitely works if I add the user_id field in the answer, but without it does not work.

Comment: You might have some leftovers, that should definitely work. Try `php artisan migrate:refresh`, then the original command again (without user_id).

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Are you absolutely positive that the contents of create_cards_table are those you posted?

Comment: Yep, pretty sure, but I am going to start the tutorial from the beginning again just to be certain.

Comment: You might wanna try and login to mysql manually to drop the database you're using and recreate it.

Comment: I will try that, however it is sqlite that I am using so it will take me a minute to work out how to do that.

Comment: Well I followed the course to a tee and it still shows the error, I am clearly missing something but I am going to push on with the course anyway. Thanks for your help, as it does solve my problem I will select it as the answer, really, thanks for your time!